# Как отфильтровать DataFrame чтобы остались значения больше медианного?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, фильтрация

Есть таблица

```
    country                    country_size     contamination_territory
132 Russia                     17075400.0       63.49
71  Canada                     9984670.0        27.66
77  China                      9596960.0        81.24
152 United States of America   9372610.0        35.74
```

И есть недописаная функция, которая должна искать в колонке данные больше медианы и возвращать их (надеюсь правильно передал мысль).

```py
def filter1(data, column, median):
    result = []
    for row in data:
        if len(row[column]) < median:
            result.append(row)
    return result
```

Как дописать ее чтобы работало? Оставте коментарии, почему имменно так.

Comment: А почему, с Вашей точки зрения, в таком виде оно не работает, не поделитесь?

Comment: не знаю как обратиться из функции к столбцу

Comment: подробнее, пожалуйста, и в сам вопрос, а не в комменты

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если таблица - это Pandas.DataFrame, то и решать вопрос нужно используя векторизированные методы Pandas:

```
res = df.loc[df["country_size"] > df["country_size"].median()]
```

результат:

```
In [10]: res
Out[10]:
    country  country_size  contamination_territory
132  Russia    17075400.0                    63.49
71   Canada     9984670.0                    27.66
```

Comment: _Если таблица - это Pandas.DataFrame_, а какая может быть ещё? Всё уже в метках и заголовке. Так понял, отвечено было ещё по первой редакции вопроса.

Comment: @0xdb, я дополнил метки вопроса, но не был на 100% уверен, что правильно понял что автор имеет ввиду. Наверное после принятия ответа можно исходить из того, что речь идет все-таки о Pandas DataFrame ;)

Comment: Да, я это и имел ввиду.